# Google Maps Javascript Api v3 Paid API quota limit Per devise or sharable across all users in the world?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

In my rails project i am doing server side geocoding. Android application finds the latitude and longitude and sends the latitude and longitude to my rails application. Rails application does the reverse geocoding to find the address on the basis of latitude and longitude provided by the android mobile application.

This works fine but the problem is that Google provides limitation on the server side geocoing. Google only provides 2500 request per day which is not enough for me. In order to overcome this Google provide paid service which allows 100000 request per day for a single domain and as per my application needs even 100000 request per day are not enough.

So my question is if i buy Google map licence paid API service that provides 100000 geocode request per day and use client side geocoding (Google Maps JavaScript API v3) on mobile application instead of server side geocoding, then 
what will be the limitation on mobile devise.

Is it 100000 request for each mobile devise per day or 100000 request will be shared by all users in the world who are using this application???

Why i am asking this question because if 100000 geocode request are shared by all  users in the world and if my application is installed by 10000 users and if 100000 users made a geocdoe request then my quota will easily finished.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Typically, quota for Google APIs is per project. Any device or user that uses the project credentials consume quota for the APIs of that project. In this case though, client-side geocoding quota limits are per user session, thus scale with your user base and you are unlikely to hit the quota limit, unless you make batch requests. You can find more Geocoding quota information and strategies [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#quota-limits).

Comment: what is mean by "unlikely to hit the quota limit" ?? does it mean that there is also a quota limit for client side geocoding.

Comment: Yes, there is a quota limit with client side geocoding, but to my understanding of the documentation, it is per map session. If you're making thousands of calls per map session, I think you need to reconsider how you approach things.

Comment: if i buy Google API business service then it provides 100000 request per day.if i use this Google API business service in client side then what will be the limitation on client side??. will it provide 100000 request per mobile devise or 100000 request are sharable acrosss all the users who are using mobile application.